# Null Pointer Exception when changing activities

Tags: android

I am Getting a null pointer exception when I click an options button that changes activities here is the buttons code

```
 options.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) 
                    {
                        Intent i = new Intent(Main_Timer_Activity.this,Options_Activity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
```

And I Only have an initialise method on the options activity

```
 private void initialise()
    {
        minutes = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtMin);
        seconds = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtSec);
        coffeeS = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinCOF);
        save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (Options_Activity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,coffee);
        coffeeS.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Here is the options Activity on create

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_options_);
        initialise();

        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(Options_Activity.this,Main_Timer_Activity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Comment: back Button havn't initialized yet..

Comment: It was the back button must have been a late night last night thanks for the support HIGHLY APRECIATED

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your `back Button`. Should solve the problem

Comment: It was the back button must have been a late night last night thanks for the support HIGHLY APRECIATED

Answer (score 0):

Have you added permission in manifest file?

```
 <activity
            android:name=".Main_Timer_Activity"
             />
```

Answer (score 0):

the `coffee` variable in the `initialise()` method may be null..

Comment: How would i make it not null as it is a spinner with an array

Comment: you will need to provide what values you need the `Spinner` to show.. For example:- `String coffee = {"coffee1", "coffee2"};`

Answer (score 0):

check your coffee array in Array adapter.... Is it null???

Comment: i have not enough reputation so i answer the quw insted of comment... :(

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your button like:

```
Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getIdOfYourButton);
```

then perform click action like:

```
back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "clicked on backimage ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
//more code
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have not posted your logcat error, so not so much clear the exact reason of it but we can see that you have not initialized `back` button in `initialise()` function. do that as

```
private void initialise()
    {
        minutes = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtMin);
        seconds = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtSec);
        coffeeS = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinCOF);
        save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

        back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.back_button_id);

        ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (Options_Activity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,coffee);
        coffeeS.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

and make an entry of this activity in `manifest.xml` file also i.e.

```
 <activity android:name="Options_Activity"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Null pointer exceptions are caused because of the misprint ids.In your case,you forgot to initialize the back button. Initialize your back button.